# How Do I indicate on Linkedin that I'm a Freelancing Consultant?

Tags: linkedin, freelancing, consulting

I'm an IT professional, who has worked in different positions, in different companies for the last 8 years. Since March, I've transitioned to an Independent Freelancing Consultant Role, where I provide consultancy to several Different organizations.

What I mean by this, is that I'm not working at any one place full time. I might work for Company A for 15 hours/Week, Company B for 15 hours/Week & Company C for 10 hours/week. Some of the consulting Gigs are short term, about 2 months. To confirm, I've not founded, nor own any LLC or similar.

[image]

When I go to add this position on Linkedin, I see that the Company Name is required, and It seems that there is no good way to add this kind of information to my Linkedin profile.

How do I indicate this role on Linkedin, and add all the skills, and roles?

Comment: Just put Freelance Consulting in there. Your work will be bulleted underneath so no one will care that it's not an official company name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do I indicate this role on Linkedin

In the Company Name field, put "Self-employed".

In the Title field, just put "Independent Freelance Consultant".

In the Description field, add detailed explanation of this role.